# Hudson : Directory not found

Tags: hudson

Using **Hudson**, I try to run a job for tests. The job run a **.bat** file in which I have this command line

```
subset v: "C:\A_Directory\"
```

When this line is executed I get in the console of Hudson an error that **the directory "C:\A_Directory\" was not found** . However this directory exists and I can access it manually.

What might be the problem? Could it that I must specify a relative path to the workspace of Hudson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command in my question tries to create a virtual disk. The used syntax is wrong.

Here the correct one :

```
subset v: "C:\A_Directory"
```